# Correct implementation of a set function for pointer variable

Tags: c++

What is good practice to implement a set function for a class variable which is stored in a pointer (due to the need of polymorphism).

Do I pass a pointer to the set function or the object by reference?
Also what is the textbook way of making sure no memory leaks exist?
(Unfortunately, I can't use smart pointers.)

The way I see it I have two options:

```
class A {
  B* b;
  setB(B& newB) {
     delete b;
     b = &newB;
  }

  //vs:

  setB(B* newB) {
     delete b;
     b = newB;
  }
};
```

Comment: You cannot call delete, unless you certainly know the passed value was actually created with new. I'd recommend using a smart pointer instead (e.g. `std::unique_ptr<B>`).

Comment: What exactly do you mean with correctly implement? Are you refering to good practices or how to use the C++ language?

Comment: I'm referring to good practice –

Comment: @user695652 As mentioned _good practice_ would be not to use raw pointers at all.

Comment: If you know your pointer should never be a null pointer use a reference; references cannot be NULL so the client does not get a chance to pass an invalid pointer. Also make sure that 'b' is a valid pointer to valid data; you cannot delete null pointers, data that was already deleted, or has never been initialised.

Comment: I do not think you need smart pointer here because it should be easy to maintain a good internal state.

Comment: In theory it is also easy to make pigs fly. Go with the smart pointer. The overhead is minimal and the safety benefits huge.

Comment: The textbook way of doing it is smart pointers. There are no textbook ways, or indeed any ways, of doing it correctly otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Since C++11, I believe the correct way is to use an `std::unique_ptr<B>`:

```
#include <memory>

class A {
  std::unique_ptr<B> b;
  void setB(std::unique_ptr<B>&& newB) {
     b = std::move(newB);
  }
};
```

and to call it, do:

```
std::unique_ptr<B> b(new B(/* ... */));
obj_A.setB(std::move(b));
```

A parameter of the type `std::unique_ptr<B>&&` will ensure to the user of your function that you are taking the ownership of the pointer to yourself.

EDIT:

As univise pointed, OP doesn't want to use smart pointers. I can't infer from the question why is it so, but if it is about resource usage, know that using a `std::unique_ptr` like this has zero overhead, either in compiled code size or in pointer object size.

Comment: Although your answer ok, you should note that the OP said she/he cannot use/would like to avoid use of smart pointers because it is being used in an embedded system.

Comment: @univise Why do you say OP is coding for an embedded system?

Comment: @Ivella The comments said so, they have just be edited by the OP. The unedited version stated that we are dealing with an embedded system. Your answer is good. EDIT: Now, in the question it states: "Unfortunately, I can't use smart pointers." at the end of the second paragraph.

Comment: Wondered that myself. In embedded systems safety should trump virtually all other considerations.